# How to export Array to Excel with EPPlus?

Tags: arrays, excel, powershell, epplus

I need to export large amount of data to Excel with PowerShell.

First I used this great module https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel that works but is to slow for my data.

It's writing the data with the EPPlus.dll cell by cell so it's slow.

The dll also has methods to load an array of objects or a DataTable at once which is much faster, I can get the DataTable method to work but I can't figure out how to load an array with "LoadFromArrays"

Example:

```
# Install and Load
Install-Package EPPlus -Scope CurrentUser -provider Nuget -Source https://www.nuget.org/api/v2
Add-Type -path "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\PackageManagement\NuGet\Packages\EPPlus.4.1.1\lib\net40\EPPlus.dll"
# Initialize Data
$Path = 'C:\Temp\Test.xlsx'
$pkg = [OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage]::new($Path)
$ws  = $pkg | Add-WorkSheet -WorkSheetname 'test'


# Single Cell Works
$ws.Cells['A1'].Value = 8

# DataTable Works
$myDataTable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$null = $myDataTable.Columns.Add( 'Column1' )
$null = $myDataTable.Columns.Add( 'Column2' )
$null = $myDataTable.Columns.Add( 'Column3' )
$null = $myDataTable.Rows.Add( 'value1','value2','value3' )
$null = $myDataTable.Rows.Add( 'valueA','valueB','valueC' )
$null = $myDataTable.Rows.Add( 'valueD','value2','valueE' )
$null = $ws.Cells['A1'].LoadFromDataTable($myDataTable,$true)

# How to Load an Arrays?
$Process = Get-Process
$null = $ws.Cells['A1'].LoadFromArrays($Process)
$Process = @([PSCustomObject]@{A = 1},[PSCustomObject]@{A = 2})
$null = $ws.Cells['A1'].LoadFromArrays($Process)
# I get the Error:
#[2,1] Cannot convert argument "Data", with value: "System.Object[]", for "LoadFromArrays" to type "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Object[]]": "Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Object[]]"."


# Save to disk
$pkg.Save()
$pkg.Dispose()
```

Thank you

Comment: C# example, but not sure how to convert https://gist.github.com/MikeHook/1132183. BTW, PowerShell itself is also making it slow, because with great power comes great .. overhead. It should be a bit faster with VBScript or C# if those are an option.

Comment: Any reason not to use the native `Export-Csv`, then open using EPPlus?

Comment: @Slai Yes I think the syntax conversion is the problem, regarding the performance of PowerShell I think it's not a big problem as using LoadFromDataTable works pretty fast.